# Не могу декодировать ответ с помощью json_decode

Tags: php, json, curl

Работаю с api, отправляю логин, пароль, несколько значений.
В ответ получаю заголовок, тело. В теле данные в формате json.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 49282
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   ...продолжение заголовка...
>    { "PriceModels": [ { "ArticleId": 886110, "ArticleCode": "6117302", "TradeMarkId": 10204, "TradeMarkName": "GIRLING", "Description": "Текст", "ArticlePriceInfo": [ { "Price": 2528.58, "Qty": 10.0, "DeliveryTerm": 5, "Multiplicity": 1, "City": "", "OfferKey": "SO421уу1==" }, { "Price": 2834.94, "Qty": 2.0, "DeliveryTerm": 4, "Multiplicity": 1, "City": "", "OfferKey": "98Iiууу==" }

Если писать так:

```
...
$json = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $json;
?>
```

то ответ приходит, как в примере указанном выше.
Если добавить

```
$obj=json_decode($json);
echo $obj;
```

То ответ пустой.

Весь код вместе с json_decode:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ch_url."/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $Login.':'.$Password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ApiKey=".$ApiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$headers = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);

foreach ($headers as $header) {
if (strpos($header,"Token:")!==false) {
$token = array($header);
}
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ch_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,false);

$json = curl_exec($ch);

$obj=json_decode($json);

curl_close($ch);

echo $obj;
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что вся проблема в том, что если curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); то не проходит авторизация

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы получаете ответ вместе с заголовками. Понятно, что такую строку Вы не распарсите. Вам нужно либо вручную выкусить само тело сообщения, либо перед вторым запросом попросить не показывать заголовки

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

Comment: Если писать curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);, то опять же приходит пустой ответ. Собственно догадывался что дело в заголовке. Но пока не смог найти причину пустого ответа если просить не показывать заголовки.

Comment: @John Какой именно ответ приходит? Напишите какую строку возвращает `curl_exec`

Comment: Через curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); получил код 401 ошибка авторизации, это если curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

Comment: @John Эту опцию нужно выключать **только** перед вторым запросом. А в первом она должна быть **включена**